# Create a C# Core.NET project using System.IO.Ports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I need to create a C# Core.NET project (to be able to run on Linux) but when I create my project with Visual Studio 2017, I can't use the namespace System.IO.Ports even if it is present in Core.NET 2.1.4 which I installed (cf. screenshots)

My question is simple: how should I configure my project to be able to use this feature?

I precise that I already used System.IO.Ports on this computer for Unity3D projects, but in this case Unity3D handles all the Visual Studio configuration. So i really don't know how to do, but I know that it is possible on this computer.

[image]

Comment: You likely need to install the [System.IO.Ports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports) nuget package

Comment: No I did not tried that, but isn't it supposed to be already installed if I am able to use it with unity projects?

Comment: "Installed" is not really the concept here. The dependency is brought in to relevant projects as needed. The unity project might have some pre-configured dependencies - without looking I wouldnt know

Comment: Ok thank you for this precision, I still lack some reflex with C# and VS. I imported the package and now it's ok, so problem solved !! Thanks guys !! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the extensions to netstandard/netcore are separate dependencies, installed using nuget.

In this case you're looking for [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports).

It can be installed using the command `install-package system.io.ports` in the package manager console