# How to download System.IO.Ports for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I am trying to read and display information from a USB port in VisualStudio C# Windows Forms Application and I would like to use Serial Port commands. However, I am not able to get my system to recognize "using System.IO.Ports"... I have tried searching the internet but I cant figure out how to get the program to import and use the package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a C# Core.NET project using System.IO.Ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545031/) and [Accessing the SerialPort class using .Net Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258554/) and [Using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort in .NET Core 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711396/) and [How to add a .dll reference to a project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992286/) and [Getting local Nuget Package into Visual Studio Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828503/)

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET? See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework for more info. If using .NET, you need to install the NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, If your winform app is a .net frameowrk app, you could try to use the following code directly to use the SeriPort class.

```
using System.IO.Ports;

SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
```

If your winform app is a .net core app, you need to install the nuget-package `System.IO.Ports` and use the same code to use the class.